# DataTable.Select with converting string value to Date format and sort it

Tags: vb.net

I have a data table that is being returned by a 3rd party component, so I have no way of changing the SQL string to get what I want. So, I get a table with several columns, all of them are Strings. One of the columns is **BILLDATE** which is of type string, but actually holds a date in a **MM/DD/YYYY** format.

Issue: I need to sort the records in descending order and pick the record with the biggest date.

CODE:

```
Dim dataRows As DataRow()
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt = GetTable()
dataRows = dt.Select("", "BILLDATE DESC")
```

Sample data:

```
10/23/2010
9/23/2010
8/23/2010
7/23/2010
6/23/2010
```

From the sample data, the `9/23/2010` record is returned as the first record, not the `10/23/2010`.
Here is what I tried:

`dataRows = dt.Select("MAX(CONVERT(DateTime,BILLDATE))", "")` - run-time Error

`dataRows = dt.Select("", "Convert(BILLDATE,'System.DateTime')")` - run-time Error

I would prefer not to iterate through all the records to get the latest date and select it. Any ideas?

EDIT 1 - 2012-12-07 4:42pm:
Added definition for dataRows. It is of type `DataRow()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) with multiple format strings. You need them since your "dates" sometimes have one and sometimes have two places. I would use Linq instead:

```
Dim ordered = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
              Let billDate = Date.ParseExact(
                              row.Field(Of String)("Billdate"),
                              {"MM/dd/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy"},
                              Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                              Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
              Order By billDate Descending
              Select row
' if you want to create a new DataTable from the rows: '
Dim tblOrdered = ordered.CopyToDatatable()
```

Comment: VB GUI shows an error `Visual basic does not support this kind of initialization` on line `{"MM/dd/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy"}, _`

Comment: @George: Just wanted to note that i've forgotten to add the descending order above. Corrected my answer accordingly. If you are using .NET 2.0 you cannot use Linq.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LastDate As Date = dt.AsEnumerable().Max(Function(a) Convert.ToDateTime(a("BILLDATE")))
```